# Tic tac toe ends before it should

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

I've tried to create a tic-tac-toe game however X usually wins before it should, for example: row 1 column 2 ends the program on the first move, but if I write row 2 column 3 first, it works fine for the most part. Some of the things obviously could be better(O or X replacing alredy occupied tiles and so on) but I'd rather get this part fixed first by changing the code a little.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tic_Tac_Toe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Field(List<char[]> p) { 
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(p[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(p[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(p[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(p[3]);
            Console.WriteLine(p[4]);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
        }

        static List<char[]> read(char player, List<char[]> p) {
            bool end = true;
            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;
            do {
                Console.WriteLine("Which row would you like to pick?(1,2,3)");
                row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Which column would you like to pick?(1,2,3)");
                column = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
                if (row == 1)
                {
                    row = 0;
                    end = true;
                }
                else if (row == 2)
                {
                    row = 2;
                    end = true;
                }
                else if (row == 3)
                {
                    row = 4;
                    end = true;
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is no such row");
                    end = false;
                }
                if (column == 1)
                {
                    column = 0;
                    end = true;
                }
                else if (column == 2) {
                    end = true;
                }
                else if (column == 3) {
                    column = 4;
                    end = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is no such column");
                    end = false;
                }
            } while (!end);
            p = write(player,p,row,column);
            return p;
        }

        static List<char[]> write(char player, List<char[]> p, int row, int column) {
            p[row][column] = player;
            Field(p);
            return p;
        }

        static bool Test(List<char[]> p) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i=i+2)
            {
                if ((p[i][0] == 'X' || p[i][0] == 'O')|| (p[0][i]=='X' || p[0][i] =='O'))
                {            
                if (p[i][0] == p[i][2] && p[i][2] == p[i][4]) 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if (p[0][i] == p[2][i] && p[2][i] == p[4][i])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (p[0][0] == 'X' || p[0][0] == 'O'  )
            {            
                if (p[0][0] == p[2][2] && p[2][2] == p[4][4])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (p[0][4] == 'X' || p[0][4] == 'O')
            {
                if (p[0][4] == p[2][2] && p[2][2] == p[4][0])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        
            return false;
        }

        static void run(List<char[]>p) {
            int i = 0;
            Field(p);
            bool end = Test(p);
            for (i = 0; i < 9  && !end; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    p=read('X',p);
                    end = Test(p);
                }
                else
                {
                    p=read('O', p);
                    end = Test(p);
                }
            }
            if (Test(p))
            {
                i--;
                if (i % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player X won!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player O won!");
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<char[]> Field = new List<char[]>();
            char[] row1 = {' ','|',' ','|',' '};
            char[] row2 = { ' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' ' };
            char[] row3 = { ' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' ' };
            char[] sep1 = { '_', ' ', '_', ' ', '_'};
            char[] sep2 = { '_', ' ', '_', ' ', '_' };
            Field.Add(row1);
            Field.Add(sep1);
            Field.Add(row2);
            Field.Add(sep2);
            Field.Add(row3);
            run(Field);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried rewriting the part about rows and columns a bit, but that didn't really help. I think the problem might around the part where the program determines who wins, but I'm not quite sure how I could fix that part. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: When you step through this code in a debugger, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used at the time?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert is a good guide.

Comment: You are missing the game loop. The function  `run()` executes once and then terminates. Break the game up into steps and repeat the gameplay steps in a `while()` loop until the termination criteria is met.

Answer (score 0):

I shall Advice you, in the first place to try and write cleaner code, your code is very hard to read and I am pretty sure it contains a lot of logical errors.

However after a quick look at your Test function with the input (row:1,column:2) I figured out the following:

1. at this line `if((p[i][0] == 'X' || p[i][0] == 'O') || (p[0][i] == 'X' || p[0][i] == 'O'))` true will be returned when `i = 2`
2. so the next line `if (p[i][0] == p[i][2] && p[i][2] == p[i][4])` specifically at the part `p[i][0] == p[i][2]` compares tow empty chars wich is always true.

As a last note: Don't include the field lines '|' in your input array, this makes things just harder for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a good case of why OOP programming is better than functional programming for program maintenance/debug point of view.

It is really hard to follow the logic, and this is partly because your whole game model consists of a `List<char[]>` which is really the visualization of the game.

So how do you check to see if someone has won? This is the part where creating a `class TicTacToe { }` with some kind of representation of the player positions in an 2D array would make it much easier to check for end conditions (filled board), and if any player has one (three marks).

In the code above you have a for loop with conditional end condition, which is not the way for loops are designed to be used. Use a `while()` loop and check for the end conditions *at every iteration*.

Finally the input & validation can be simplified once the game model is developed.

---

An example game model could be

```
public class TicTacToe
{
    // 2D array holding 0 for empty spot
    // 1 for player one, and 2 for player 2
    public int[,] Board = new int[3,3];

    public bool HasPlayerWon(int player)
    {
       // with a loop you can check if any row or column
       // of the Board contains the number in `player`.
       // Don't forget to check the diagonals also.
    }

    public bool IsBoardFull()
    {
       // check if any spots in `Board[,]` are still zero
       // if they are then return false, otherwise return true
    }

    public bool TryPlayerTurn(int player, int row, int column)
    {
        // try to mark row,column with player
        // return true if spot was empty, false if illegal move
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Visualization code here   
        // Use StringBuilder to add grid and player marks
    }
}
```

And the game logic would be something like this

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var game = new TicTacToe();
        int player = 1, turn = 0, row, column;
        while(true)
        { 
            turn++;
            // Show the game board
            Console.WriteLine(game);

            do
            {
                // Process user input
                row = ...
                column = ...

            }
            while(!game.TryPlayerTurn(player,row,column));

            if(game.HasPlayerWon(player))
            {
                // player just won
                break;
            }

            if(game.IsBoardFull())
            {
               // game is a tie
               break;
            }

            // Switch players
            player = 3-player;
        }
    }
}
```